# basic jquery in rails not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using my first jquery but dont know what's wrong with it. on W3schools its working good but as soon as i implement it in  my rails application then BOOM it goes wrong.
here is my "myquery.js" file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

my application.html.erb contains

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "myquery"%>
```

my index.html.erb contains

```
<p>hide my paragraph</p>
```

i dont know what went wrong in this code. when i click on paragraph this should disappear but...

Comment: this is beenalready added
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
yes i have all four of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding

```
//= require myquery
```

to app/assets/javascripts/application.js

and then in application.html.erb do this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application"%>
```

this page http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html explains rails' asset pipeline

Comment: <%= javascript_include_tag "application"%> only this or as well as this <%= javascript_include_tag "myquery"%>

Comment: i was lacking in //= require myquery. thanks @nathan

Comment: no problem, glad to help :) ... <%= javascript_include_tag "application"%> only this one. Rails will compile all of the javascript files referenced in application,js into 1 file, and compress it for you when running in production. This helps your apps to download faster.